# List all variables in a Freemarker template

Tags: java, freemarker

We have a dynamic Freemarker template. We have 1 template containing the global document structure and different configuration with dynamic blocks. These blocks are evaluated with `block.content?interpret`.

In the main template and blocks we also have variables which need to be filled. I wonder if it would be possible to extract a list of all the variables in the resulting template?

The only thing that I can think of, currently, is to parse the resulting template and use a regexp (or something like that) to extract anything between `${(...)}`. But maybe there is a nicer extension-point in Freemarker that I'm not (yet) aware of.

We would like the list of variables so that we can communicate to the user which variables need to be filled in (we have a UI to enter things but we also want to provide a meta-model through a service).

Comment: There are some answers on SO and on the web (surely you will find them). But what they will say is that this is not supported, because of the dynamic nature of the language. It's impossible to tell in general what variables are used. Unless we heavily restrict what language construct can be used.

Comment: That is what I suspected and kind of deduced from the internals of FreeMarker, just wanted to make sure. Thanks, we will have to look for another solution then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think you can (and want) to automate this based on a template. For example, what variable(s) are used here?

```
${lt + [a, b, c, d]?min gt 5 ? lte : f}
```

If you would be able to resolve a property name from a template, you don't know what type it is.

I don't know your exact use case, but as you tagged your question with Java, you probably do something like this somewhere:

```java
template.process(model, writer);
```

If you use custom Java objects for this, they would be ideal to generate documentation.

Comment: The point is it is a generic solution and the model is nothing more than an input `Map` passed to use through a web service. So not really a fancy object structure due to the generic nature of things. FreeMarker probably parses the expression and retrieves the values on the fly from the model instead of preparing things beforehand. So I actually want this, but I doubt it is possible (hence the question, as in my searches in the sources and debugging sessions I couldn't find anything that could help with this).